# Trying to filter 4 different houses from an api

Tags: javascript, api, filter, rendering, event-delegation

I'm trying to separate characters based on what house they belong to in the API (http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters)

I have tried using .filter and .map, but have been unable to achieve that goal, I don't know if this is the right place to ask for help understanding how to achieve my goal.

Here is the code:

```js
const studentArray = [];

async function getStudents(url) {
  const student = await fetch(url);
  const jsondata = await student.json();
  jsondata.forEach((student) => {
    studentArray.push(student);
  });
}

getStudents("http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters/students").then(() => {
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="/testing/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/testing/styles.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="name" class="container"><button onclick="Gryffindor">Test</button></div>
      <div id="name" class="container"><button onclick="Slytherin">Test</button></div>
      <div id="name" class="container"><button onclick="Ravenclaw">Test</button></div>
      <div id="name" class="container"><button onclick="Hufflepuff">Test</button></div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using .then() on getStudents(), but the function doesn't return a promise(), doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your onclick's don't call functions

Comment: @StudioWorks `getStudents` is `async`. It implicitly returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a look [here](https://hp-api.herokuapp.com/) and there seems to already be an endpoint set up to get characters from particular houses if that's what you want to do?

E.g. fetch(http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters/house/gryffindor) will return an array of students in Gryffindor.

You could refactor your getStudents function to take the house as an argument and make a GET request to the `http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters/house/:house` endpoint, using a template literal.

Also your onClick isn't invoking any function. I suggest you have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) for an example of how to use `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach, and especially for the chosen API, is to fetch all student-data exactly once.

From this data one can create an own index of house-specific student-lists. For the chosen API one would realize that there are actually students listed with no relation/link into any house. [And the API itself does not provide students which are not associated with a house](https://hp-api.herokuapp.com/).

Thus, the task which does render the house-based filter-items can take this additional information (no house) as much into account as the option of displaying any student regardless of the house (all students).

The next step would initialize the filter handling which is the rendering of student-items from the currently chosen (`click` event) house-specific student-list.

It uses the technique of [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Thus, there is a single listener subscribed to a single element which is the root-node of the students filter (instead of subscribing the listener again and again to each filter-item).

```js
function emptyElementNode(elmNode) {
  [...elmNode.childNodes].forEach(node => node.remove());
}

function createFilterItem(houseName) {
  houseName = houseName.trim();

  const elmItem = document.createElement('li');
  const elmButton = document.createElement('button');

  elmItem.dataset.filterLabel = houseName;
  elmButton.textContent =
    (houseName === '') && 'No House' || houseName;

  elmItem.appendChild(elmButton);
  return elmItem;
}
function createStudentItem(studentData) {
  const elmItem = document.createElement('li');
  const elmImage = document.createElement('img');
  
  elmImage.src = studentData.image;
  elmImage.alt = elmImage.title = studentData.name;

  elmItem.appendChild(elmImage);
  return elmItem;  
}

function renderStudentsFilter(houseBasedIndex) {
  const houseNameList = Object.keys(houseBasedIndex);
  // console.log({ houseNameList });

  const filterRoot = document
    .querySelector('[data-students-filter]');

  if (filterRoot) {

    const filterListRoot = houseNameList
      .reduce((rootNode, houseName) => {

        rootNode
          .appendChild(
            createFilterItem(houseName)
          );
        return rootNode;

      }, document.createElement('ul'));

    const allStudentsFilterItem =
      createFilterItem('All Students');

    allStudentsFilterItem.dataset.filterLabel = 'all-students';

    filterListRoot.appendChild(allStudentsFilterItem);
    emptyElementNode(filterRoot);
    filterRoot.appendChild(filterListRoot);

    return filterRoot;
  }    
}
function renderStudentItems(studentList) {
  const displayRoot = document
    .querySelector('[data-student-list]');
 
  if (displayRoot) {

    const listRoot = studentList
      .reduce((rootNode, studentData) => {

        rootNode
          .appendChild(
            createStudentItem(studentData)
          );
        return rootNode;

      }, document.createElement('ul'));

    emptyElementNode(displayRoot);
    displayRoot.appendChild(listRoot);
  }
}

function handleStudentsFilterFromBoundIndex({ target }) {
  const filterItem = target.closest('li[data-filter-label]')
  const { dataset: { filterLabel } } = filterItem;
  // console.log({ filterItem, filterLabel });

  const studentList = this[filterLabel];
  renderStudentItems(studentList);

  window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
}
function initializeStudentsFilterHandling(filterRoot, houseBasedIndex) {
  filterRoot
    .addEventListener(
      'click',
      handleStudentsFilterFromBoundIndex.bind(houseBasedIndex)
    );
}

function createStudentsFilterByHouse(studentList) {
  const houseBasedIndex = studentList
    .reduce((index, student) => {

      const houseName =
        student.house?.trim() ?? '';

      (index[houseName] ??= []).push(student);
      return index;

    }, {});

  // console.log({
  //  studentList,
  //  houseBasedIndex,
  // });
  const filterRoot = renderStudentsFilter(houseBasedIndex);

  houseBasedIndex['all-students'] = studentList;

  initializeStudentsFilterHandling(filterRoot, houseBasedIndex);
}

async function main() {
  const url = 'http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters/students';

  const response = await fetch(url);
  const studentList = await response.json();

  createStudentsFilterByHouse(studentList);
}
main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 32px 0 0 0!important;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px 2px 3px;
}
ul li img {
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
  width: auto;
}
ul li img[src=""] {
  height: 98px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
}
[data-students-filter] {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<article data-students-overview>

  <navigation data-students-filter>
    <em>+++ initialize house based students filter +++</em>
  </navigation>

  <section data-student-list>
  </section>

</article>
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing, ill read through it and try to see if I can understand how the code works, appreciate the answer. I notice the buttons are created in the script, is it possible to attach these to existing buttons?

Comment: The entire approach is about fetching all data at once and generate the buttons from the actual existing / non existing house names (because the overall student list is the single source of truth). The API for instance does not provide students which are not associated with a house (the `house` property is an empty string). And of cause the approach already takes into account different ways of creating the filter buttons. For this the handler got subscribed to the `click` event of the `[data-students-filter]`'s root node ... see ... [_event-delegation_](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Comment: @Vlskib ... Could the OP meanwhile improve her/his approach? Are there any questions left?